# join query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 3 tables in mysql:

`t_group`:

```
id | groupid
--------------
1    group1      
2    group2
```

`t_user`:

```
id | userid | groupid
----------------------
1    user1    group1  
2    user2    group1
3    user3    group2
4    user4    group2
5    user5    group2
```

`t_order`:

```
id | orderid | userid
---------------------
1    order1    user1      
2    order2    user2
3    order3    user2
4    order4    user4
```

I like to get the number of users and the number of orders by group.
My query is as follows:

```
SELECT t_group.groupid, COUNT(t_user.id) as num_user, COUNT(t_order.userid) as num_order
FROM `t_group` 
left join t_user on t_group.groupid=t_user.groupid
left join t_order on t_order.userid=t_user.userid
GROUP by t_group.groupid
```

But I got the weird result:

```
------------------------------
groupid | num_user | num_order
------------------------------
group1    3          3 
group2    3          1
```

The actual number of users in group1 is 2, but it shows 3.
Isn't it possible to get my desired result in a single join query?

Comment: COUNT(t_order.userid) as num_order  Really ?

Comment: Also specify the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach to achieve desired result:

```
select temp1.groupid,temp1.count_user,temp2.count_order from 
  (select count(distinct (u.userid)) count_user, u.groupid
   from t_group g
   inner join t_user u on u.groupid= g.groupid
   group by u.groupid
  ) temp1
left join
  (select count(distinct (o.orderid))count_order, u.groupid
  from t_group g
  inner join t_user u on u.groupid= g.groupid
  inner join t_order o on u.userid = o.userid 
  group by u.groupid
  ) temp2
on temp1.groupid= temp2.groupid
order by temp1.groupid;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7e97d9fece256e71a35ca8544fb12c5b)

Comment: Great!.. It works perfect! and thanks a lot for your kind example in DB fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try with inner join:

```
SELECT t_group.groupid, COUNT(t_user.id) as num_user, COUNT(t_order.userid) as num_order FROM `t_group` 
INNER JOIN t_user ON t_group.groupid=t_user.groupid
INNER JOIN t_order ON t_order.userid=t_user.userid
GROUP by t_group.groupid
```